# How to remove comments from preceded by #, but preserving #include and #!

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I need to remove the comments section on piece of code for diff purposes.

I use grep and sed to remove all lines starting with #, // and ;, as well as multiple lines enclosed by /* and */.

One issue is that this rule also removes the lines starting with #include and #!/bin/whatever which are valid code statements.

Is there a way to preserve the lines containing #include and #! at the start but remove the rest of the lines starting with # using either grep or bash.

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: Try looking into negative lookaheads. I'm not familiar with sed, but something a bit like this might work: `#(?!!|include)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` to escape, in other words if u want to preserve `#` use it like `\#`. But could you please be more specific about the programming language to give you an accurate answer

Answer (score 0):

`egrep "^ *([^ #]|#!|#include|$)"`

Comment: The above line works. Is there a way to include a negative match for // as well?

Comment: Sure: `"^ *([^ #/]|#!|#include|/([^/]|$)|$)"`. However, multi-line comments are not quite as simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think simplest would be to pipe your original grep command with `egrep -v` like this:

```
grep "your-pattern" *.c | egrep -v "^\s*#(!|include|define)\b"
```